# Не работает @media в css

Tags: html, css

Не могу понять, в чем проблема. Порядок правильный, после всех стилей, а выполняется все равно только с 1024px

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 760px) {
    .header {
        color: black;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
    .header_inner {
        padding-bottom: 100px;
    }
    
    .logo {
        font-size: 40px;
    }
    .navbar {
        padding-top: 10px;
        flex-direction: column;
    }
    
    .navigation {
        width: 100%;
        font-size: 22px;
        font-weight: 400;
    }
    
    .main_title {
        font-size: 40px;
    }
    
    .main_about {
        font-size: 18px;
        line-height: 30px;
    }
    
    .button {
        border: 2px solid;
        font-size: 22px;
        padding: 20px 30px;
    }
    
    .story_logo img {
        width: 100px;
        margin: 70px 50px 0 0;
    }
    
    .section_title {
        font-size: 30px;
    }
    
    .section_text {
        font-size: 18px;
        opacity: 85%;
        line-height: 28px;
    }
    
    .story_video {
        height: 35vh;
    }
    
    .play_story {
        font-size: 22px;
    }
    
    .section_subtitle {
        word-spacing: 1px;
        font-size: 19px;
    }
    
    .expertise_item .section_text {
        padding-top: 10px;
    }
    
    .item_name {
        font-size: 16px;
    }
    
    .name {
        font-size: 18px;
    }
    
    .works_item {
        height: 130px;
    }
    
    .contacts_item {
        padding: 15px;
        border: 2px solid;
    }
    
    .footer_inner {
        padding: 40px 0;
    }
    
    .footer_inner .navigation {
        font-size: 16px;
        padding-top: 30px;
    }
    
    .media {
        width: 290px;
        padding-bottom: 90px;
    }
    
    .media img {
        width: 40px;
    }
}
```

Comment: meta: viewport есть ?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag

Comment: вставил, но теперь при масштабировании появляется белая полоса справа

Comment: я то откуда это вижу

Comment: Попробуй всё что выше засунуть в `@media screen and (min-width: 1024px) { }`

Comment: переместите `1024` выше, чем `760`